# Given that $f''(x)=f(x^2)$, what is $f''(x^3)$

Tags: derivatives

I'm pretty sure you can't do $f''(x^3)=f((x^3)^2)$. To Clarify I DO NOT mean $(f(x^3))''$ but $f''(x^3)$

Comment: for all x or for some x?

Comment: question didn't really specify. I assume it's for all x then.

Comment: Are there no other known properties of the function, like perhaps that it's a polynomial (in which case the solution would be trivial but I'm brainstorming).

Comment: Original question: Given that f'(x)=g(x) and g'(x)=f(x^2), what is f''(x^3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just $f(x^6)$. Other than that, you can't really tell much.

Comment: why can you just plug in x for x^3

Comment: It is just substitution. As you correctly noted $f''(x^3)$ is different to $(f(x^3))''$.

Comment: I kind of need a function to visualize what's going on. Is there a function where that situation is true?

Comment: @RichardChang What's the context of this problem?

Comment: The original question was just: Give that f'(x)=g(x) and g'(x)=f(x^2), what is f''(x^3). To be honest, I think they messed up the notation.

Comment: If $f''(x) = f(x^2)$ then these two things are the same function.  Therefore if I do something to the first function, and to the second function, the results must also be the same.  So if I substitute $x^3$ into both, the results should be the same for both.  so $f''(x^3)=f((x^2)^3) = f(x^6)$.

Comment: This might sound stupid but I just want to make sure that my reasoning is correct. So because x could be any value, whether we plug in x^6 or any number it will be true. So therefore if we plug in x^3 it should still work since the "x" values are the same on both sides.